# Carousel: Change ring's angle

Tags: android

I want to make use of this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel).

And change ring's angle and icon's angle to get something like this:

[image]

But I don't know how. Is it possible?

Comment: you need to play with the angles. That's rite. But it is not that simple at least.

Comment: I supposed that, but maybe someone could tell me how to start =p